# When i check my database there are no new entries. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up page</title>
</head>
<body>



        <form method="post" action="signup_redirect.php">
            username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
       // The user would enter the desired username and password.
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect" .mysqli_connect_error();
}



$sql = "INSERT INTO test (username, password) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."')";
}//Takes the values that the user has submitted and inserts them into my table called "test".


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a form which would take the users desired details then if the submit button is pressed it runs through the rest of the php code.I also have the sql statement which is meant to add data but when i check my database there are no new entries.

Comment: You don't run the query...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (username, password) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."')";
```

After that run query

```
$sql_qry=mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
if (mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbCon);
}
```

after, $sql query you have written